# How can I run Hamachi as a service?

Tags: windows, hamachi

Many of you are probably aware that the free version of [Hamachi](http://www.logmeinhamachi.com/) no longer officially supports running as a service.

Is there any way I could still get Hamachi to run as a service?

I need to be able to remotely access my computers from outside of the network when NO user is logged into the computer. Specifically this is important for remote desktop, file sharing, file syncing, and computer backups.

Comment: Asking for software recommendations is usually not constructive, so I removed that part. If people say it's not possible and happen to suggest alternatives, so be it. I don't know Hamachi all to well but isn't TeamViewer Host a possibility here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears Hamachi still technical is running as a service but they have chose to monitor by some other means whether the user is actual active or not. If the computer is on the lock screen where you select the user account to login to (even if a user is actually logged in) Hamachi will turn off.

For the above mentioned reasons I have decided to switch to [NeoRouter](http://www.neorouter.com/). NeoRouter so far appears to do everything Hamachi did and then some. Built in Windows Remote desktop, Wake-on-Lan, shared folders, command line interface, run from USB drive, network bridging, etc. The only catch is you need one computer that is always on to act as the "server" to tell the other computers how to connect to each other.

A note on setting up the NeoRouter server: When I first installed it it would not connect (which you can test via https://www.neorouter.com/Dashboard/domainstatus.aspx). I solved this by checking the Windows firewall and noticing the NRServer and NRService exceptions were being blocked in my private network.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that Hamachi doesn't run as a service anymore, it is more so that it requires Hamachi UI to be running for it to work.  Obviously, if one is not logged into their computer, the UI won't be running.

There's a similar question on ServerVault, where the answer allows for transfer of the session back to the local machine instead of logging out (and terminating the UI).

Here's the command: (Note: Number 1 below is your session ID. To know what your current session ID, in the console, run query user or open the task manager and go to users and look at your session ID)

> tscon 1 /dest:console

The only caveat is that your local session is now unlocked, so if you'd like  lock the computer as well, create a .bat file with the following commands:

> tscon 1 /dest:console
>   rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation

Here's the above mentioned link for more details: https://serverfault.com/questions/7107/how-to-prevent-hamachi-service-stop-when-remote-desktop-disconnects-on-windows-x

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i added more details for the answer to be self contained.

Answer (score 1):

it is now 2018, and as I can see, Hamachi runs as a service if you buy a subscription for your network.

I could not find any documentation saying that, but as my experience when I upgraded my network with a paid subscription, I didn't even have to restart the machine or Hamachi, it was automatically reconfigured and run.

Comment: This is exactly what the original question was about and doesn't add anything new. Please do not post answers unless they are helpful.

Comment: Oh okay, I did not see the word "free". It is better if the title of the question says "How can I run the free version of Hamachi as a service?" Sorry for disturbing.

Comment: There are many ways information can be presented more clearly. It behooves us as answerers to read the questions as carefully as we can to make sure we understand as much as possible about the facts of the matter. That said, don't leave. There's still plenty of questions here, and even us high-rep members started at the bottom at one time. So read the Help section, learn how we work, and then dive in.

Comment: @music2myear This definitely adds something new.  I am running into this problem, it is 2018 and I would like to know if purchasing a paid subscription for Hamachi will cause it to run as a service and resolve the problem indicated in the question.  Here is a user pointing out that indeed Hamachi will run as a service if you purchase the paid subscription, even though it doesn't seem to be documented.  That is not indicated anywhere else.

Comment: I can confirm that upgrading to a paid subscription for the Hamachi VPN network resolves the problem.  You can disconnect from (i.e.) RDP and Hamachi stays active on the machine.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution here @DanNissenbaum. However, your needs are different from OP, who specifically needed to know whether a free product could be manipulated to run in a particular way. Essentially you have a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You can make use of the tool called exe2svc, hosted on [here](https://code.google.com/p/exe2svc/).
It can turn any .exe into a service. Just edit the .xml file to Your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved the problem is the following. I went into `policy editor > Computer Conf. > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Connection Host > Connections > Restrict Desktop Remote services users to a single RDP session > Disabled the rule`. After that you can:

- go to the local machine (or use any remote software like TeamViewer)
- log in with your credentials
- start-up Hamachi
- LOCK THE ACCOUNT so it will stay logged on

Now if you log in with RDP and go to `task manager > users` you will see that you have two users logged in. After that, you can log in\log out with RDP how many times you want it will not log off the local session and thus Hamachi will stay on.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).