# How to change from Public network to Private network - Windows 10 and using Powershell?

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, remote-desktop, remote-access

I am using [Hamachi](https://superuser.com/q/526633/730576) to connect from home to the office and vice-versa - but I am having problems when connecting from office to home.

At home Hamachi is on a public network, how can I change this to private network?

I saw this question but it is Windows 7:
[How to change from Public network to Private network](https://superuser.com/q/292678/730576)

Plus I would like it in Powershell.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found this article:
[How to force a network type in Windows using PowerShell](https://www.itprotoday.com/powershell/how-force-network-type-windows-using-powershell)

Get the powershell script running:

```
#check the network you got - get the names
Get-NetConnectionProfile


#the name of my network is - Network 2 - that's the one I am making private
#make it private
Set-NetConnectionProfile -Name "Network 2" -NetworkCategory Private

#check out the results
Get-NetConnectionProfile
```

[image]

to check it through Windows:

1. Right click on the network thingy at the right hand side - choose `Open Network & Internet settings`

[image]

1. Choose `Network and Sharing Centre`
   [image]
2. Then you can see your Networks - notice `private` now

[image]